# Custom MapIcon image wrong size in UWP app

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I've got a UWP app with a map view. For some of my MapIcons, I need to set a custom image. Others use the default image. My custom image is approximately the same size as the default image. Additionally, I generated different sizes for different screen scales, and named them accordingly (for example, MyIcon.scale-200.png, etc).

I tested this by running the app on my computer, a Surface Pro, and setting the scaling to different values in the Settings app. It seems to work. As I choose larger scales, I get larger custom MapIcons, and the custom icon is similar in size to the default icon.

However, my customers report that it is not working correctly when I distribute my app. They are sending me screen shots that show the custom MapIcon either much larger, or noticeably smaller than the default one. I can't reproduce or explain these results.

What could cause this?

Comment: I figured out an important detail just now. It works correctly as long as I adjust ONLY the scale value and NOT the "Display Resolution". Apparently, many of my customers are using a "Display Resolution" that is different than their native screen resolution, and this triggers the issue. I'm surprised by this, and don't have any idea what to do about it.

Comment: Could you share more detail about repro steps?

Comment: Simply put, if I select a screen resolution other than the native resolution, my custom map icon is not the same size as the default icon. But if I use the native resolution, it is, even if I change the scale.

Comment: The fix I came up with is to use a custom icon for all the map points and not rely on the default icon.